# Change character set of downloaded file via response headers

Tags: symfony, character-encoding, twig

I have to download twig file with ISO encoding, but although I changed the response's charset it keeps being an UTF-8 file when I download it.

This is the code of the route handling file download:

```
public function exportAction() {

    $path = 'page/1/sort/userId/order/desc';

    $slugs = $this->get('path')->convert($path);

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Payroll');

    $request = $this->get('request');

    $response = $this->render('AcmeBundle:Payroll:csv.html.twig', [
        'list' => $repository->getCsv(),
        'week_txt' => date( "d.m.Y", strtotime("last wednesday"))."-".date( "d.m.Y", strtotime("tuesday this week")),
    ]);

    $handle = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
    $header = array();

    fputcsv($handle, (array)$response);

    rewind($handle);

    $content = stream_get_contents($handle);
    fclose($handle);

    $response->setCharset('ISO-8859-2');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="export.csv"');

    return $response;
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem before, you need to call the `prepare()` method of the Response object before sending it to the client, like below.

```
    // ...
    $response->setCharset('ISO-8859-2');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="export.csv"');
    $response->prepare();

    return $response

}
```

I'm not sure why, I think it's because it prepares the response based on the request received, I can only assume that Symfony detects the difference between the charset of the request and the response and adds the header because of the difference, but this may also be a bug.

The docs for this method are below.

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html#method_prepare

Comment: But I'm using symfony 2.5, not 2.0 It doesn't work here, adding $request as a parameter changes nothing.

Comment: Have you tried setting it as `$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=ISO-8859-2');` rather than using the `setCharset()` method?

Comment: Yes, I have. Right now I have set both, via setCharset() and ;charset